# primitive elements in cyclotomic extensions with Eisenstein minimal polynomial.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Maybe this is not a deep question. But I am asking this question just for my own curiosity.

Wild unimportant question: Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(e^{{\frac {2\pi i}{m}}})$ be the $m^{\rm th}$ Cyclotomic field. For which primes $q$, there exists a primitive element $\alpha \in K$ such that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is Eisenstein  at $q$?

All that I know is that for $m=p^k$, the minimal polynomial of $(-1+\zeta_{p^k})$ is Eisenstein at $p$.

> My question: Suppose that $p \mid m$, is there any primitive element for $K=\mathbb{Q}(e^{{\frac {2\pi i}{m}}})$, whose minimal polynomial is Eisenstein at $p$?

Comment: In general, if $K = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of a polynomial $f$ that is eisenstein at a prime $p$, then $p$ is totally ramified in $K$. (See [these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/totram.pdf) for a proof.) In particular, if $m$ is not a prime power (or $2$ times a prime power), then $K$ has no Eisenstein primitive elements.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thanks for introducing that note. You are right. Theorems 3.1 and 3.2 give a complete answer to the question.